# Python String Double Splitting?

Tags: python, list, sorting, numbers

So heres my issue I am given a string like this one

```
01000200030004020511050006000702051108020511090205111002051111020511120205111300140205111500160017001800190020002100
```

then I have to separate it into something that will end up looking like this

```
[['01', 00], ['02', 00], ['03', 00], ['04', 020511], ['05', 00], ['06', 00], ['07', 020511, ['08', 020511], ['09', 020511], ['10', 020511,], ['11', 020511], ['12', 020511], ['13', 00], ['14', 020511], ['15', 00], ['16', 00], ['17', 00], ['18', 00], ['19', 00], ['20', 00], ['21', 00]]
```

So first I thought lets try using split and maybe that will work so that was my first try and it just came out like this

```
['01', '02', '03', '0402051105', '06', '0702051108020511090205111', '20511110205111202051113', '1402051115', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '021', '']
```

After that failed I though to myself that I am going to have to split twice to get rid of the '00' and the '020511', so I used the method

```
re.split('020511|00', theStr)
```

Doing that method I get this back...

```
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '1', '2051111', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '021', '']
```

But its not in the format that I wanted it in and its not coming out right, when I split it will just get rid of the values that I was like say '10' will come out as 1 because the program splits the 0's and Im not entirely sure how to come up with a solution for this so any help is apreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: so basically the separator is an incrementing two-digit number? that's... weird. what if, say, your `'04'` second-part itself contained `'05'`?, e.g. `[04, 050611], [05, ...]`?

Comment: Is this a defined encoding?

Comment: No, I'm not entirely sure what you just meant but after every 01 or 02 or whatever it only goes up too 21, after that will either be a 00 or a 020511 and I just have to group them together, so say like you will have 01 and lets say there is two 00's after that I would have to group them like this [['01', 00]]

Comment: I have te impression, that you are processing BCD-encoded numbers. If this is true, use binascii.unhexlify first.

Comment: The string is already decoded. Its just numbers now in a string

Comment: Do you always know that the first of your number pairs are sequential? Are 00 and 020511 the only other half?

Comment: Uhm, Im pretty sure you mean is its always going up by 1? like it will go 01, 02, 03 and then the phrase after will always be 00 or 020511, it will never change

Comment: Is there is always a 6 digit number after each group (or 2 when it's "00")?

Comment: You never know what its gonna be because it will change, Thats mainly the issue why I cant figure it out, because it will randomly be either 6 or 2, like it will either be 00 or 020511, nothing else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.findall()` to find the digits with length 2 that followed by `00` or `020511`:

```
>>> re.findall('(\d{2})(020511|00)', theStr)
[('01', '00'), ('02', '00'), ('03', '00'), ('04', '020511'), ('05', '00'), ('06', '00'), ('07', '020511'), ('08', '020511'), ('09', '020511'), ('10', '020511'), ('11', '020511'), ('12', '020511'), ('13', '00'), ('14', '020511'), ('15', '00'), ('16', '00'), ('17', '00'), ('18', '00'), ('19', '00'), ('20', '00'), ('21', '00')]
>>>
```

And if you want the result in a list you can use `re.finditer` that returns an iterator and a list comprehension to convert the relative groups to list:

```
>>> [list(i.group(1,2)) for i in re.finditer('(\d{2})(020511|00)', theStr)]
[['01', '00'], ['02', '00'], ['03', '00'], ['04', '020511'], ['05', '00'], ['06', '00'], ['07', '020511'], ['08', '020511'], ['09', '020511'], ['10', '020511'], ['11', '020511'], ['12', '020511'], ['13', '00'], ['14', '020511'], ['15', '00'], ['16', '00'], ['17', '00'], ['18', '00'], ['19', '00'], ['20', '00'], ['21', '00']]
>>>
```

Comment: Does this put it into a list? or?

Comment: @BSD_ This returns a `list` of `tuple`s.

Comment: Awesome Thanks so much everyone.